# copy Array to Member of Struct in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, microcontroller, avr-gcc

I'm trying to transmit data wireless. My payload-struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct
{
   uint8_t data[3];
} data_t
```

I also have an array in my code:

```
uint8_t data_to_be_copied[3];
```

if I try to simply assign each other I get the following error:

```
msg->data = data_to_be_copied;
```

incompatible types when assigning to type 'uint8_t[3]' from type 'uint8_t *'

using a for-loop my microcontroller crashes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  msg->data[i] = data_to_be_copied[i];
}
```

Same happens, when I try to use memcpy:

```
memcpy(msg->data, data_to_be_copied, 3);
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does `msg` actually point to something? Or did you just say `data_t *msg;` without giving it any space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`msg->data` is an array.

As such, it does not have an l-value, and you cannot change it.

That's why you're getting a compilation error for the first option mentioned above.

For the second and third options mentioned above, you're getting a memory access violation during runtime, probably because your `msg` variable is not initialized to point to a valid memory address.

Assuming that you have `data_t* msg` declared in the right place, you still need to initialize it:

```
data_t* msg = (data_t*)malloc(sizeof(data_t));
```

You should also make sure that you `free(msg)` at a later point in the execution of your program.

BTW, you have not specified the entire structure of your program, but a simple `data_t msg` instance might be sufficient for your needs (in which case, you don't need to use the `malloc` and the `free`).

And as mentioned in a comment by **@Shahbaz**, if you **do** end up using `malloc` and `free`, then you need to make sure that your platform (OS or BSP) supports dynamic memory allocation (AKA *heap*).

Comment: Since it's a microcontroller environment, it possibly doesn't support dynamic memory management. _Possibly_.

Comment: Thanks, I somehow forgot memory allocation. It works fine with malloc, but tells me it tries to free a non-heap object

Answer (score 0):

You have some possibilities:

memcpy (msg->data, data_to_be_copied, 3);

or change data_to_be_copied to

```
data_t data_to_be_copied;
```

and assign the whole thing: *msg = data_to_be_copied

or if msg has actually more members, declare a struct that has an array of three chars as its only member.

If it crashes, then most likely msg is NULL or some uninitialised pointer.